# Anyone know how to animate this?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    view.frame.origin.y -= 150
}
```

What this does is, this moves the view by the specified amount(150) when the keyboard appears. The problem is I don't know how to animate this or is it even possible to animate this? Hope someone can help me, thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you can. Simply wrap the call into an animation block:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= 150
}
```